# Direct Sums and Jordan Normal Form

Tags: linear-algebra

***Problem***

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\Bbb C$ and let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. Suppose that $V = V_1 ⊕ · · · ⊕ V_s$
where the $V_i$ are $T$-invariant subspace of $V$ for $i = 1, . . . , s$.

a) Show that $ker(T) = ker(T \vert V_1) ⊕ · · · ⊕ ker(T|V_s)$ (restriction notation).

b) Deduce that, for all $λ ∈ C$ and all $k \in \Bbb N_{>0}$, we have
$ker(T − λI_{V} )^k = ker(T|V_1− λI_{V_1})^k ⊕ · · · ⊕ ker(T|V_s− λI_{V_s})^k$.

**Thoughts**

This question comes out of a chapter in my linear algebra textbook concerning Jordan Normal Form.I have solved part $a)$ but I am unsure how part $b)$ is related. Hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply part $a)$ to the linear operator $(T-\lambda I)^k$, and note that
$$(T-\lambda I)^k\vert_{V_i}=(T\vert_{V_i}-\lambda I_{V_i})^k.$$